# LXDE doesn't work on fresh Lubuntu 18.04 on a dual boot PC with broken Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu, windows-10, lxde

I know the question is about Lubuntu, but I hope I can still get an answer.

So, I had a Windows 10 laptop, on which I installed Lubuntu using dual boot. Everything worked fine, even when Windows basically got quite corrupted, and never bothered fixing it. I couldn't get to the system, but all my files were untouched, so they just stayed there. 
However, in a very silly manner, I deleted some of the Lubuntu system files, and it wouldn't boot properly, so I decided to reinstall it (all personal files on windows partition anyway). The installation would get stuck on something related to updating grub or finding another os, so I had to cancel the installation, but it would report installation was successful anyway.

I can boot using the grub command line, and get to the login screen. However, once I log in, there's only the wallpaper, the mouse pointer, and the trash icon (that when clicked would bring up PcManFm without the top bar with the program name and close, maximize and minimize buttons). No taskbar, key shortcut for the terminal does not work, and I am out of ideas, other than to delete the Windows partition and then install Lubuntu, but I want to keep these files, and I have no method of making a backup (there's about 500gb of data), and perhaps I'll want to fix windows in future (not right now).

Any help to run Lubuntu would be appreciated.

**Edit:** Some few thousand reboots later, the taskbar showed up somewhat corrupted, but the terminal shows up rectangles instead of characters. Then the system hung up, and I was forced to reboot, and now I don't have the taskbar yet again

**Edit2:** I can run Lubuntu live from a USB, so maybe I can do something from there?

**Edit3:** Perhaps I should mention it earlier, but the pc is running on 7y/o hard drive and giving errors on a bad sector

Comment: My bad, I meant LXDE. I'll change that.

Comment: What happens if you right-click on the desktop? Do you see any sort of context menu?

Comment: Nope. Nothing shows up on right-click.

Comment: What happens with `Ctrl+Alt+F2`? Does that open a terminal for you? If it does, after you provide your username and password, run `sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop`. If that is successful, close the terminal using `Ctrl+Alt+F7` and reboot.

Comment: It did open the terminal with readable characters, however, running said command promted to manually configure dpkg (sudo dpkg --configure -a if i remember correctly), after which it went into the block of text with some errors, still updating, and can't quit. I'll see if I can upload a screen cap.

Comment: Said screen cap: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1cfy53ZnSLuwVgPRVsLyvPv2VZlbhTC/view?usp=drivesdk It just keeps on scrolling.

Comment: Your screen image shows read errors on device sda1 which I assume is your thumb-drive, so either your download was imperfect, or it was badly written to the thumb-drive (unless sda is your disk, so I'd check your SMART disk health! just to be safe).  Before you 'try lubuntu' there is a 'check disc media' - run it & I suspect you'll discover errors, showing either bad download or bad-write, or an actual faulty thumb-drive.

Comment: I did that earlier, the thumb drive is ok, sda is, in fact my 7y/o hard drive.

Comment: I searched for "buffer i/o error on dev sda1, logical block 0, async page read" and found https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2333961 and one post there suggests that your hard drive maybe failing.

Comment: Using a live usb and Disks utility, I performed Smart self-test, which my drive failed. Can this be the reason behind all that malfunctioning? Or is it because of Windows not letting the install finish?

Comment: @JonesII Yes, that is the reason.